# How to send more 5000 character to next page

Tags: php, javascript, html

I need to save a content into a file. The content is more than 5000 character. I cant able to send this through url as query string. Its showing **Unspecified error**. How to achieve this. I am using PHP here. So, i tried to send this content value's through ajax concept to another php file for storing. After a button click i want to save the generated content into a file - without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 13):

Use a POST instead of a GET, as GETs are restricted to 2000 characters or thereabouts, depending on the browser and web server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a lot about PHP, but query string is not the only way to send data from a page to another, you can try session variables, cookies, save and retrieve from a db, ....

Because Query strings have a limited number of char, different from a browser to another